# I have verified the google-api Oauth2 but in the next step the sent an email. tier 2 Cloud Application Security Assessment (CASA) google API

Tags: google-cloud-platform, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, gmail-api

I am using Google Oauth2 with Gmail API in my laravel project. The use of Gmail API is to access attachments only that the user has received and download attachments. The verification has been done but in the final step, I got this email and I don't know what to do, any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: You got any solution ?

Comment: unfortunately not?

Comment: You got any solution? If yes, please answer your own question in details. I have also the same question.

Comment: Can you please share your experience ? Which steps you followed ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to perform a security assessment that is written up in detail in [the link](https://appdefensealliance.dev/casa/tier-2/tier2-overview) that you can see in your email. This involves doing a static code analysis and a dynamic scan of your live application. Once done, you'll need to sign up to the CASA portal and submit the artefacts the two scanning tools have generated for you.

You will also need to address any security vulnerabilities marked as FAIL in your report, or prove that they are false-positives.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can you explain the steps in details ? Please update your answer. I also have the same situation, and we don't know anything about it.

Answer (score 0):

I was like you... a little bit lost. First you have to do a local scan to get the code alert for your source code (CVE high severity must be fixed before submitting to Google).
When your local test is done, you have to send your source in a specified format using Fortify Scan (i'm still here as it is not easy to produce the file).

Please find below the first step:
For my case it is a Windows WPF application using the Google OAuth API.

Here my steps to get the documents:

1. Get the Config.yaml file from google web site but don't follow the procedure because it is no more working (not updated):
   https://appdefensealliance.dev/casa/tier-2/ast-guide/static-scan
   Check the working instructions from https://docs.fluidattacks.com/tech/scanner/standalone/casa
2. Install docker for Windows, run it and no need to do something else
3. Create a folder on a disk, in this example: D:/Docker/
   Copy on it the file 'fluid-Dockerfile', rename it to 'Dockerfile'
4. In this folder create a new folder for your source code to be analyzed, in this example D:/Docker/myApp/
   Copy on this new folder the file 'fluid-config.yaml', rename it to 'config.yaml'
   Copy on this folder your source code (in this example it is a WPF application, i copied all the project folder (including bin...))
5. Open Powershell in the folder (right click in folder d:\docker)
   Execute this command
   docker pull ghcr.io/fluidattacks/makes/amd64:latest
6. Then this command with the path to folder to analyze (in this example D:/Docker/myApp)
   docker run -v D:/Docker/myApp:/working-dir ghcr.io/fluidattacks/makes/amd64 m gitlab:fluidattacks/universe@trunk /skims scan ./config.yaml

Let it run, and you will receive your csv file with result to submit to the google website https://rc.products.pwc.com/